# Iterate sub-items Ansible with sublements

Tags: ansible

Have task which copies each user's key

```
- name: SSH Keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    key: "{{ item.0.ssh_key.0.key }}"
    state: "{{ item.0.ssh_key.0.state }}"
  when: 
    - item.1 == 'all' or item.1 in group_names or item.1 == inventory_hostname
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ users }}"
    - servers
```

Var list:

```
users:
  - name: user1
    ssh_key:
      - key: 
        - "key1.user1"
        - "key2.user1"
        - "key3.user1"
        state: present
    servers:
      - server1
  - name: user2
    ssh_key:
      - key: 
        - "key1.user2"
        - "key2.user2"
        state: present
    servers:
      - all
```

**QUESTION:** How can we allow users to copy multiple keys? Without deleting **servers** from with_subelements.
When starting the task, either the last key or an array with keys is copied, depending on how we write it in var list.
In this format copied last key.

```
- key: "key1.user1"
- key: "key2.user1"
- key: "key3.user1"
```

In this array.

```
- key:
  - "key1"
  - "key2"
```

Comment: Why are you using `with_subelements` here? You don't ever to be using anything from the `servers` key. Can you update the question to show what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: I run the playbook on all servers.And the servers variable for each user specifies which servers this user should be created on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's fit the structure of the data to this purpose. For example,

```yaml
users:
  - name: user1
    ssh_key:
      - "key1.user1"
      - "key2.user1"
      - "key3.user1"
    state: present
    servers:
      - server1
...
```

It's possible to loop `include_tasks`. For example, create the task (test it with `debug` first)

```yaml
shell> cat conf_authorized_key.yml
- name: SSH Keys
# authorized_key:
  debug:
    msg:
      - "user: {{ item.0.name }}"
      - "state: {{ item.0.state }}"
      - "key: {{ iitem }}"
  loop: "{{ item.0.ssh_key }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: iitem
```

Then include it in the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    users:
      - name: user1
        ssh_key:
          - "key1.user1"
          - "key2.user1"
          - "key3.user1"
        state: present
        servers:
          - server1
      - name: user2
        ssh_key:
          - "key1.user2"
          - "key2.user2"
        state: present
        servers:
          - all

  tasks:
    - name: Loop include_task
      include_tasks: conf_authorized_key.yml
      loop: "{{ users|subelements('servers') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.1 }}"
      when: (item.1 == 'all') or
            (item.1 in group_names) or
            (item.1 == inventory_hostname)
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [Loop include_task] ****
skipping: [localhost] => (item=server1) 
included: /export/scratch/tmp/conf_authorized_key.yml for localhost

TASK [SSH Keys] ****
ok: [localhost] => (item=key1.user2) => {
    "msg": [
        "user: user2",
        "state: present",
        "key: key1.user2"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=key2.user2) => {
    "msg": [
        "user: user2",
        "state: present",
        "key: key2.user2"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=2 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```